# Forwarding email as inline messages and not as attachments in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, forwarding, attachments

When I forward messages in Thunderbird 2.0.0, the forwarded message is sent as an attachment.

Where is the setting so that forwarded messages are copied inline in the new message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this in the Options across the board:

> Tools > Options > Composition > General

There you will see a setting:

> Forward messages:

Change from **As Attachment** to **Inline**.

If you've set yourself to view all headers when reading emails then you'll see all the headers thrown into the inline view. Change that if you don't want or need to have such a verbose dump when forwarding emails.

> View > Headers

Answer (score 0):

In your preferences click `Composition` then just below that in the `General` tab there is a drop down box.